# How do I clear a SQLite database field?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Probably a really simple question, but I have a table in which a column is not set by default. The user can set the contents of that field, which works fine, but they should also be able to clear the field. How do I reset the db field? Its affinity is `real`. Do I set an empty string in the field? Null? Thanks.

Comment: It's a **number**. So set it to **0** (it seems an appropriate default for a number). If 0 is not an option, and the field is **nullable**, then use **null** as its value.

Comment: The number is used in calculations _unless_ the field is in its default empty state. That's why 0 won't cut it.

Comment: I updated my comment to include this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ContentValues.putNull(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#putNull%28java.lang.String%29)

```
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
```

`args.putNull(KEY_RISK_AMOUNT);`

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
UPDATE myTable SET myField = NULL
```

It (quite obviously) requires that `myField` is NULLABLE.